# Groovy Script: List / Map Collection

Tags: groovy

I've created a script which I'm using to simulate the behaviour of a SOAP service in SOAP UI (as a mock service) for sprint testing purposes but am having problems when trying to iterate over a List I've created. The List is made up of a number of Maps, and each Map contains a List. It should look something like this:

```
[[Rec: 1, Items: ["AB123","BC234","CD345"]],[Rec: 2, Items: ["AB123","BC234","CD345","DE456"]]]
```

And this is the code I have to build up the List:

```
def offerMap      = [:] 
def outputList    = [] 
def offerItemList = [] 

def outputMap     = [:] 
def outList       = [] 

def item          = "" 
def rec           = "" 

offerItemList.add("AB123") 
offerItemList.add("BC234") 
offerItemList.add("CD345") 

offerMap.put("Rec",1) 
offerMap.put("Items",offerItemList) 

outputList.add(offerMap) 

log.info "OUT: outputList.size ${outputList.size()}" 
log.info "OUT: offerItemList.size ${offerItemList.size()}" 

offerMap.clear() 
offerItemList.clear() 

offerItemList.add("AB123") 
offerItemList.add("BC234") 
offerItemList.add("CD345") 
offerItemList.add("DE456") 

offerMap.put("Rec",2) 
offerMap.put("Items",offerItemList) 

outputList.add(offerMap) 

log.info "OUT: outputList.size ${outputList.size()}" 
log.info "OUT: offerItemList.size ${offerItemList.size()}"
```

And this is the the code I have to iterate over the list:

```
outputList.each { 

    log.info "OUT: outputList.size ${outputList.size()}" 

    outputMap.clear() 
    outputMap = it 

    rec = outputMap.get("Rec") 
    log.info "OUT: REC ${rec}" 

    outList.clear() 
    outList = outputMap.get("Items") 

    outList.each { 

        item = it 
        log.info "OUT: Item ${item}" 

    } 
}
```

But this is not giving me the results I expect. The first problem is that the `outputList.each` loop appears to immediately be jumping to the second entry in the list, as witnessed from the output:

```
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: outputList.size 1 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: offerItemList.size 3 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: outputList.size 2 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: offerItemList.size 4 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: outputList.size 2 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: REC 2 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: Item AB123 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: Item BC234 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: Item CD345 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: Item DE456 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: outputList.size 2 
Fri Nov 03 17:54:32 GMT 2017:INFO:OUT: REC null
```

I'm running out of ideas and fear I may be missing something fundamental due to my lack of experience with Groovy.

Comment: You are adding the list, then clearing it and adding it again. It is the same list. Create a new list each time for each element

Comment: Why don't you just define it like you have in the question? `[Rec: 1, Items: ["AB123","BC234","CD345"]],...etc`

Comment: It appears that you need to build the mock service response based on the request received. Would you mind showing input and desired output?

Comment: The problem I have is that the offerItemList list is being constructed dynamically, based on an iteration I'm performing (not shown in the example to reduce complexity). For this reason I can't define the list up front; I have to define an empty offerItemList and then continue to add to it in my iteration. Once all the items (for that particular iteration) are added to offerItemList I then want to add offerItemList to offerMap and then add offerMap to outputList. And then repeat the process for the next set of offer items...

Comment: I think I understand the issue in that when I add offerItemList to offerMap I'm adding a pointer rather than the content of the list. Similarly, when I add offerMap to outputList I am also adding a pointer and not the actual map contents (which is why I end up with 2 entries in outputList that are exactly the same).

Just need to work out how I add the contents of offerItemList / offerMap rather than just the pointers...

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it represent your problem? You keep mentioning a dynamic nature which you don't show

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. Note that the goal isn't entirely clear, but this is an educated guess (also unclear on `Rec` versus `Row` in your example at the top).

```
def outputList = [
['Rec': 1, 'Items': ["AB123","BC234","CD345"]],
['Rec': 2, 'Items': ["AB123","BC234","CD345","DE456"]]
]

outputList.each { outputMap ->
    // is row == Rec ???
    def row = outputMap['Rec']
    println "OUT ROW: ${row}"

    def items = outputMap['Items']
    items.each { item ->
        println "OUT Item: ${item}"
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
$ groovy Example.groovy
OUT ROW: 1
OUT Item: AB123
OUT Item: BC234
OUT Item: CD345
OUT ROW: 2
OUT Item: AB123
OUT Item: BC234
OUT Item: CD345
OUT Item: DE456
```

Comment: Hi Michael, 

Thanks for taking the time to respond, much appreciated. Apologies for the row / rec confusion, changed it from row to rec but obviously not caught them all, fixed now.

Will give your suggestion a go, thanks again.

Comment: I've had a quick look and don't think this will work for me as I'm constructing offerItemList / offerMap dynamically (so can't define them up front).

Bask to drawing board!

Comment: You should probably delete this question. It wasn't 100% clear originally and certainly isn't now.

Comment: Was that comment really necessary?

Comment: Apologies if my comment was gruff. Stack Overflow has an ethos of making the web a better place. The question, as it stands now, is vague, and your comment re: dynamically appears to be a new requirement. What value does this post have for new readers? What if people spend time (as I did) trying to help you, and miss the comment/new requirement? The original question should be clarified if you still seek help; otherwise consider deleting it.